# Bootstrap grid-layout

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, grid

I am newbie with bootstrap gridline system so I got stucked when I tried to create that (advanced?) gridview:
[image: Imgur]

So my problem is that I do not know how to organize blocks in rows, because some blocks must have difeerent height, for example height of block 5. should have the same size as blocks 3. and 2. together.

Is that even possible? Also there should be some space between blocks, so background image should fill those space.

Please help me out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you'll want to do is place divs 2, 3, and 4 in their own container div (with the class .col-md-3) and 5 and 6 in another container div (with the class .col-md-3). Make div 1 have the .col-md-6 class.

Edit: You should use a media query to make it a fixed height in the desktop, then a flexible height when it's mobile.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 980px) { #div2 { height: 500px; (or whatever)}}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Can you review my code and maybe correct it, or just give me your advice what to change to get best possible and easy code, because I think I complicated to much because my lack of experinece: http://www.bootply.com/Tv1Q3khM4x

Comment: Hmm, it's a little bit hard to tell (would be easier if there was text in the divs instead of images so I could see how flexible it is), but it does look to be responsive from what I can see.

Answer (score 2):

I think the most efficient way to do this is to simply use a single row with three columns. Your divs can stack inside the appropriate columns, and you can define the heights for each one. You can see it in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/StSmith/Z9SpM/1/

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
      <div id="box1">1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3">
      <div id="box2">2</div>
      <div id="box3">3</div>
      <div id="box4">4</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3">
      <div id="box5">5</div>
      <div id="box6">6</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your fiddle has completely different code to your answer.

Comment: Can you please paste correct fiddle url? I tested it, it's almost good :)

Comment: Updated the link, sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to do this is to declare the divs in the order you listed, and then apply a simple `float: left`. If you define the heights of each div manually it should all fit into place!

Comment: Thanks for your answer and here is another question for you. If I set height manually will be page still responsive? I do not think so.

Answer (score 0):

Rachel's got the right idea.  You really just need to nest rows into a container, then use CSS to adjust the heights.

Comment: I know you can't comment yet - but this isn't an actual answer! Please wait till you have enough rep and refrain from posting answers like this so that you don't get downvoted